# hiding <li> html tag with php

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I am making a user management system what i want to do is when the user is logged in he cant see (ex. sales employee) he cant see links for other departments, what I'm trying to do is simple but I don't know why its not working, my code is:

```
$departmentidquery = mysql_query("SELECT department_id FROM users WHERE username            = '".$username."'");
$departmnetid = mysql_fetch_row ($departmentidquery);
<ul>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
    <li <?php if ($departmnetid[0]!=1){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>  <a      href="admin.php">Admin Pgae</a> </li>
    <li <?php if ($departmnetid[0]!=2){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>  <a href="sales.php">sales Pgae</a> </li>
    <li <?php if ($departmnetid[0]!=3){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>  <a href="tech.php">Tech Pgae</a> </li>
</ul>
```

The error is:

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: departmnetid in C:\wamp\www\Ticket.sys\index.php on line 49
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: departmnetid in C:\wamp\www\Ticket.sys\index.php on line 50
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: departmnetid in C:\wamp\www\Ticket.sys\index.php on line 51
```

I am sure from the query, I already tried the trick of `display:none` with `<div>` and its working, is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You are also missing a `?>` between the `mysql_fetch_row` call and where the `<ul>` starts.

Comment: Your code assumes that `mysql_query()` was successful. You should check for errors before using the data.

Comment: You `$departmnetid` has no data therefore you are seeing `Notice: Undefined variable:` try `dump($departmnetid)` and see what you got

Answer (score 4):

You are not shifting in an out of PHP blocks as you should ... this code should read

```
<?php
    $departmentidquery = mysql_query("SELECT department_id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
    $departmnetid = mysql_fetch_row ($departmentidquery);
?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
    <li <?php if ($departmnetid[0]!=1){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>><a href="admin.php">Admin Pgae</a> </li>
    <li <?php if ($departmnetid[0]!=2){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>><a href="sales.php">sales Pgae</a> </li>
    <li <?php if ($departmnetid[0]!=3){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>><a href="tech.php">Tech Pgae</a> </li>
</ul>
```

It would also be a good idea to check to see if you actually got a value back from mysql_fetch_row

Comment: Better idea is that instead to `display:none` property remove the html tag because some technical user can inspect the code from console hope you got my point :)

Comment: i checked the query and its working(because i use it in another place in the same page) and it works well

Comment: @dianuj just as easy since we are playing in server land.

Comment: @MohammedALJakry If you are running the query make the test... if you run it twice test it twice... the world can change between the first and second query.

Comment: Better yet, run the query one time and use the results twice... then you only have to check once.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the mysql instance (instance being down, invalid user name/pass). Have you tried this?

```
if (!$departmnetid) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It's always a good practice to check if your query executed successfully and discard any connectivity issues or permissions issues on the schema itself